# Political Bantering Puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

### Simply Puns Or Cryptic Clues In **BOLD**:

---

Sitting atop a tall chair in the garden, one English Politician P was having his **Evening Beverage**,
His American Neighbour N was asking "Our Admiral can write Programs. **What about your Countess**?"
P replied "What is Programming, **according to you**?"
N elaborated "I had once written the standard *hello-world* code and **I executed** it to get the output. I can say that I am a Programmer! **What about you?**"
P quipped "**Is that true** Programming? It is only **1 or two** lines!"

N, having the **Disease of moving aimlessly**, quickly changed the topic, saying "**Oh man**! your weather is **contemptuous, it will Pour** now! Let us go in."

---

### **HINT:**

All words are related to one Area.
Name of the Program indicates that one Area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All bold passages ...

> ... can be replaced with the **name of a country**, either by paraphrasing or as a homophone.

So:

> Evening Beverage — *High tea.* **HAITI**
>  What about your Countess — *Can Ada (Lovelace)?* **CANADA**
>  according to you — *per you* **PERU** (solved by samm82)
>  I executed - *I ran*, **IRAN**
>  What about you? — *Can ya?* **KENYA**
>  Is that true — *Is real?* **ISRAEL**
>  1 or two — **VANUATU**
>  Disease of moving aimlessly — *roam mania* **ROMANIA** (disclosed by OP)
>  Oh man — **OMAN**
>  contemptuous, it will Pour — *Bah, rain!* **BAHRAIN**

Comment: Brilliant! +1! Except the third & the eighth, these were the intended answers. In a while, I will mark this Post as the Correct Answer & will also list the intended answers against the third & the eighth.

Comment: Aha, thanks! I've run a bit out of ideas. (The usual "[answer that sounds like an medical condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qatar)" isn't about moving. I hope it isn't [something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dystonia) that doesn't _quite_ fit because of the first letter.)

Comment: I think the 3rd one is rot13(cre lbh = CREH) and the 8th one might be rot13([EN](https://www.cdc.gov/arthritis/basics/rheumatoid-arthritis.html) jnaqre = EJNAQN) or something in a similar vein

Comment: @samm82 , CREH is right ! While wander is close to moving aimlessly, it lacks a Disease.

Comment: @MOehm , It must match Moving and Disease, but QT & DY do not. A look at the Geolocation tells me that DY is quite close ; longitude within 1 Degree.

Comment: My somewhat oblique comment was about a similarity between dystonia and Estonia, but the D is missing, of course.

Comment: I got the oblique comment , @MOehm , & I was Pointing out that DY (or EST) was close to the intended answer , [[ EBZNAVN == EBNZ ZNAVN ]] , within 1 Degree longitude . . .

Comment: Aha, then I just didn't understand what DY meant. I'd never had gotten the actual answer, but it seems that samm82's guess wasn't to bad.

Comment: Yeah, @samm82 got CREH correct and was quite close with wander or roam !

Comment: @Prem ahh, that makes more sense for the 8th one - I figured my guess was a long shot (I normally wouldn't pronounce "R.A." as "ruh") but you never know